# dependency on file created by recursive make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to do.

Directory structure:

```
.
├── Makefile
└── subdir
    ├── a
    └── Makefile
```

./subdir/Makefile:

```
a.copy: a
        cp a a.copy
```

./Makefile:

```
.PHONY: build_subdir

a.copy: subdir/a.copy
        cp subdir/a.copy a.copy
build_subdir:
        $(MAKE) -C subdir

subdir/a.copy: build_subdir
```

The first time I run `make`, everything's fine:

```
$  make            
make -C subdir
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/kkourt/src/tests/make/subdir'
cp a a.copy
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kkourt/src/tests/make/subdir'
cp subdir/a.copy a.copy
```

Re-runing make is also fine (nothing happens):

```
$ make
make -C subdir
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/kkourt/src/tests/make/subdir'
make[1]: `a.copy' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kkourt/src/tests/make/subdir'
```

If I update `subdir/a`, however, `./a` is not updated:

```
$ touch subdir/a      
$ make
make -C subdir
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/kkourt/src/tests/make/subdir'
cp a a.copy
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kkourt/src/tests/make/subdir'
```

If I run `make` a second time, `./a` *gets* updated

```
$ make
make -C subdir
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/kkourt/src/tests/make/subdir'
make[1]: `a.copy' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving director
```

Why does this happen? shouldn't the check of whether `subdir/a.copy` is older than `a.copy` happen *after* the `build_subdir` target is finished since it's its dependency? Is there a way to fix this?

**Edit**:

As MadScientist suggested, I added a dummy recipe and it works:

```
subdir/a.copy: build_subdir
    @:
```

Comment: It probably doesn't matter since this is a once-a-build target, but just to note that this "dummy" recipe still causes make to invoke a sub-shell.  And note, that comment is not considered a make comment, so the subshell will be sent the text `true # dummy recipe`.  If you worry about performance of the target you should choose either an empty recipe, or one like `@:` which make knows is a no-op and won't start a shell (but will still understand that it needs to re-check the timestamp).

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks! I edited my answer to include the no-op recipe. I prefer this one from your original answer, because it's more clear to see what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your rule `subdir/a.copy: build_subdir` has no recipe, make "knows" that it can't actually change the timestamp on `subdir/a.copy`.

You need add a dummy recipe to it, maybe like this:

```
subdir/a.copy: build_subdir ;
```

(note I can't test this right now but I think it'll work).